# How to get CGImageRef from CGContextRef?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, core-foundation

I am trying to add two images into context, however it does not work and throws

> GBitmapContextCreateImage: invalid context 0x0

error. I use the following code:

```
//some image
CGImageRef image = ...
//some image as well, but masked. Works perfectly.
CGImageRef blurredAndMasked = CGImageCreateWithMask(blurred, mask);
//Both images are fine. Sure.

//Initializing the context and color space
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, frameSize.width, frameSize.height, 8, 0, colorSpace, kCGBitmapAlphaInfoMask);

//Drawing images into the context
CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, frameSize.width, frameSize.height), image);
CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, frameSize.width, frameSize.height), blurredAndMasked);

//getting the resulting image
CGImageRef ret = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);

//releasing the stuff
CGImageRelease(image);
CGImageRelease(blurred);
CGImageRelease(blurredAndMasked);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
CGContextRelease(ctx);
```

this seems fine but the resulting images are all black or look very similar to this:[image: Bad image]

What should be changed in the code? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kCGBitmapAlphaInfoMask` is not a valid value for the last (`bitmapInfo`) argument to `CGBitmapContextCreate`. It is a mask (hence the name) you can use with the `&` operator to get just the `CGImageAlphaInfo` out of a `CGBitmapInfo` value. You would never pass `kCGBitmapAlphaInfoMask` where a `CGBitmapInfo` or `CGImageAlphaInfo` is expected.

Assuming you don't need a specific byte order, I believe this is the highest performance pixel format with alpha channel on iOS:

```
CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil,
    frameSize.width, frameSize.height, 8, 0, colorSpace,
    kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
```

And this should be the highest performance without alpha channel:

```
CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil,
    frameSize.width, frameSize.height, 8, 0, colorSpace,
    kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);
```